# Check if username exists: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if there is an existing user in the database, and I keep getting this error when trying to check for the username in the database.

```
Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object
```

^this is the error

Here is the top of register.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("database.class.php");
$dbn = new database(); // Define a new instance of the class "database".
$dbn->init("localhost", "root", "", "mrl-lr"); // Run the init function inside of "database" to set database connection parameters.
$db = $dbn->connect(); // Finally, run the connection and get a fully functional database connection!
```

?>

Here is the USERNAME code from the register.php:

```
// Step 5) Check if the username has not been entered.
if (!isset($_POST['username']) or empty($_POST['username'])) // ! = not; if not isset $_POST['username'] or empty $_POST['username'] then
{
    // Step 5, 1) Log an error about the username not being entered.
    $errors[] = "Username has not been entered!"; // [] is called "pushing" - pushing puts items into an array(in our case, errors).
} else {
    // Step 5, 2) Check other validations.
    // Step 5, 2, 1) RegEx Checking
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-\pL]+$/u", $_POST['username']))
    {
        $errors[] = "Username may only be numbers, letters and -'s!";
    }
    // Step 5, 2, 2) Check to see if the username is less than 4 chars or more than 46.
    if (strlen($_POST['username']) <= 4 or strlen($_POST['username']) >= 46) 
    {
        $errors[] = "Username must be 5-45 characters long.";
    }
    $count = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
    $user =  strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['username']));
    $count->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $count = $count->execute();

    if ($count->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        $errors[] = "Time to be original! That user already exists!";
    }
}
```

here is the code from database.class.php

```
<?php
class database
{

    protected $host = "";
    protected $user = "";
    protected $pass = "";
    protected $dbname = "";

    public function init($host, $user, $pass, $dbname)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->user, $this->pass);
        return ($connection ? $connection : false);
    }

    public function hashit($string, $salt)
    {
        return hash("whirlpool", $salt.$string.$salt);
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: I can't see a definition of 'rowCount', 'execute', 'bindparam' and other called functions. please include all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not re-assing the `$count` variable in this line:

```
$count = $count->execute();
```

Instead it should look like this:

```
$res = $count->execute();
```

Explenation: the `execute()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the execution succeded or not. In your code you are overwriting the `$count` statement with that boolean.

Comment: Check the file and line where the error occured and paste that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are getting no result from the database, so you can't retrieve the row count. What you need to do is something more like this:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Document");
$stmt->execute();

if ($row = $page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // logic for true
}
```

You can read about PDO's `fetch` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Edit: By the way, the prepared statement should be stripping the tags and adding slashes for you. That part is redundant.

Also, you have errors defined as an array, but you keep overwriting the whole array instead of adding to it. Try [`array_push`](http://php.net/array_push)